# why application server is shipped with cognos? what is purpose of application server in cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I heard cognos is only a reporting engine, but it seems cognos is shipped with application server and it requires some configuration to launch cognos UI. please help to understand why application server is required in reporting engine?

Comment: What do you mean by "Application Server"? Do you mean Apache Tomcat?

Comment: Yes, before cognos10.2.1 it is tomcat and after cognos10.2.1 it is websphere liberty.  I am interested to know why any application server is shipped with cognos ( apache tomcat or websphere liberty or something else)? what is the true purpose of it.

Comment: Cognos is a jsp (Java Server Page) application that requires a Java-enabled application server to function. You don't have to use the included application server. At my previous employer we used WebSphere but later switched to vanilla Tomcat. It's just much easier to setup if you used the included Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks johnsonium